# Object that accepts all method names and prints them out

Tags: ruby

I would like to create an object that accepts method names and prints them out. I should be able to call any method on it. For example,

```
obj.hello("was")
# => called hello with argument 'was'

obj.ok(["df", 1])
# => called ok with argument ["df", 1]
```

I don't want to define `hello` or `ok` in advance.

Is that possible?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I would like to create an object, that accepts variable method names […]" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: Also, please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270933/2988) to understand why "is it possible" is a poor question, and most likely off-topic for [so], and edit your question accordingly to include the *precise* problem you are having, the *steps* you have taken to solve it, and your [mcve].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy:

```
class Noop
  def method_missing(m, *args)
    puts "#{m} #{args.inspect}"
  end
end

Noop.new.foo 
# => foo []
Noop.new.bar(1,2,3) 
# => bar [1, 2, 3]
```

`method_missing` is called on every Ruby object when you call a method that does not exist. It usually ends up being handled by Object (the superclass of everything) which raises `NoMethodError`.

Note that this does not apply to the methods provided by its ancestors (Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject) which you can inspect by:

```
class Noop
  puts self.instance_methods.inspect
  puts self.methods.inspect

  def method_missing(m, *args)
    puts "#{m} #{args.inspect}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it also possible that the object does the printing truly for *any* method? `Noop.new.dup` for example doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you @StefanPochmann. `Noop.new.dup.bar(1,2,3)` will print out `bar [1, 2, 3]`. `Noop.new.dup` will not print out anything as the `dup` method is provided by a superclass (Object I think).

Comment: Yes `dup` not doing it because it's not missing is the problem I mean. Can that be changed?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can clobber over all the methods provided by Object without actually redefining them. You could get all the methods with `self.methods` and `self.instance_methods` and redefine them all with metaprogramming but that would give you an object that does not behave like any other in the ruby language so its rarely done even in the null object pattern.

Comment: So yes its possible @StefanPochmann, its just not very useful.